# Hide element when reaches top

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I am creating an animation where, on scroll, a quote shows/hides. I have managed to show it when scrolls, but I want to hide it when it reaches the top of the screen, so it will repeat the animation every time the page is scrolled.

At the moment, it's not hiding it when it reaches the top, but I can't find the reason.
Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ELxNre)

HTML:

```
<section id="cont_quote">
    <img class="img_quote" src="image">
    <article class="cont_q">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
        <blockquote>“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</blockquote>
   </article>
</section>
```

JS:

```
/* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
$(window).scroll( function(){

 /* Check the location of each desired element */
 $('#cont_quote blockquote').each( function(i){

    var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
    var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

    /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
    if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){               
        $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},1000);

    } else if($(this).offset().top) {
        $(this).animate({'opacity':'0'},1000);
    }

 }); 
});
```

Also, do you know how to fix the image on scroll? But as soon as the end of `cont_quote` is reached, unfix it?

Answer (score 0):

Hello You can try like below

```
/* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
$(window).scroll( function(){

 /* Check the location of each desired element */
 $('#cont_quote blockquote').each( function(i){

    var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
    var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

    /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
    if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){               
        $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},1000);

    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop() <  $(this).offset().top) {
        $(this).animate({'opacity':'0'},1000);
    }

 }); 
});
```

Comment: It still has the same result... it doesn't disappear when it reaches the top

Comment: Thank you, but it hides the quote, no matter I scroll or not